# How to allow others to access a web app made from a Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I deployed a web app from a Google Apps Script, but others don't seem to be able to run it.
 (It runs fine for me when logged-in to Google)

I keep getting *"Request to share"* email, even though I set the source script to be *"Public on the Web"*.

*"Execute the app as:"* is set to *"User accessing the web app"*.

A link to the app is at http://truevis.com/rations

It could be very useful to others, but right now I think that no one else can run it.

Comment: What is more important is the question - "Who can access the app". Have you set it to `Anyone` or `Anyone, including anonymous`

Answer (score 3):

The link you show here is the development link , the one that is described as "the last saved version of your code", this link is **not** shareable ... the one you should give to people is this one :

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz1SKJi5HW1r2ZHiYpjedjul-IE4vcB266kdDzDrVCE/exec

it is shown in this popup window

[image]

beside that, the sharing properties of the script file is not relevant, you could keep it private.... only the settings in this window are important to determine who has access to your app and how (meaning run as you or as user accessing the app).

You should also keep in mind that users will see the version you have chosen in this same popup window, no matter the changes you could have saved and are using in your .dev version... so think about publishing the right version.

Comment: In this pic ^^^ `Execute the app as:` should be set as the `(me) yourEmail@gmail.com` option and `Who has access to the app` should be set as `anyone even anonymous`

Comment: I used it via a Google Sheet and I had to share the excel file with everybody before it actually worked.

Comment: @takje you shouldn't, if the app is executed as "you" there is no need to share the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

What I did to get it working:

I copied the GS code to a new file, deployed as Web app, then set "Execute the app as:" "me", "Who has access to the app:" "anyone even anonymous".

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwPtys8PE8Wda_HS9rvrdftJ0TGbCfMlT5xLlfsNFt9m5uw6qM/exec

Comment: it was obviously not necessary to create a new copy... you could as easily have change the settings of the original script as I suggested.

Comment: It wasn't until this answer that I finally got my code to work for others as well. Thanks bro, stay blessed

Answer (score 2):

I think once you deploy a version with certain permission, it does not work properly if you change the permission for the same version.

Creating a new version seems to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In case it's still relevant, I was able to solve the problem by following the steps:

Initially, I have configured the deployment settings with appropriate permissions (who has access to "Anyone" and choosing "Execute the app as: Me").

After configuring the deployment, I logged out of all Google accounts in the browser where I was testing the web app. Additionally, I cleared the browser cache to ensure a clean testing environment. Once logged out and with the cache cleared, I tested the web app using a different Google account than the one used to create the web app.

Alternatively, I also tested accessing the web app using different web browsers and it worked for me.