# How Do I publish google App script url as public for anyone with or without a google account to aceess?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api

I spent hours surfing the internet for a solution on how to upload files from an Html form to google drive and I finally found the solution which is an app script that records the link of uploaded files on a google sheet.

Then here comes the most disappointing part. After I published my app script as a web app, I set

Execute the app as: **User accessing the web app**

Who has access to the app: **Everyone**

I discovered that I was the only one who could open the URL while my google account is signed in.

I didn't come this far to set up an Html form for myself alone to upload files, I need this solution so that people who visit my website can easily upload files through the form and all their uploads will be well organized on my google drive.

Below is my app script URL:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwAa0f3Wr9Q46eqNUjKu1ZZZ-JW344jbTLjJJrOUO8U90cluA8/exec

I will be so glad if anyone can tell me what I am not doing right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.
First I tried downloading Microsoft Edge Browser on my mobile and tried to open the URL on it and it opened!!!

Then I decided to logout of all the Google accounts on my smartphone, I also logged out of the email that I used in creating the URL then I tried opening the link and it did work.

So the problem remains that Web App URL will not work if you are logged in to more than one Google account on your device.

Comment: There is a know issue related to be signed in into multiple Google accounts but the question hasn't enough details to be certain that this issue might affect your web-app.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the web-app settings to

Execute the app as: me

Who has access to the app: Everyone, even anonymous

Related

- [How to allow others to access a web app made from a Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17910764/1595451)
- [How to let users access data from a Google Sheet from a Google Apps Script web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31509055/1595451)

Comment: I have tried that also. It isn't working. Do you have any understanding of the triggers?
I was just wondering if I was supposed to do something with it which I am not doing.

Comment: @AyodejiAkingbe If you still need help please post a new questions including a [mcve]